# Selectively Enable Visual Styles on Dialogs/Windows

Tags: c++, controls, themes, winapp, visual-styles

I've implemented the use of visual styles on all common controls through the use of a manifest file as directed by this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175.aspx. Is there a way to disable the use of visual styles for a particular dialog/window or a control ?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? You want a consistent interface for the entire application, not have some parts be one style and some other parts a different style.

Comment: The application crashes for some reason when visual styles are applied to owner-drawn controls. Since those were isolated to a few border cases, I figured it'd be easier disable theming on their parent dialogs than trying to debug the issue (which would have been less than easy given the fact that I haven't got the source code for the app in question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is mentioned on the page you referenced.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175.aspx#turnoff

Comment: I concur. My thanks, and apologies for the superfluous question.